# Bring a component in front of another group

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a screen with some components (labels, buttons, etc).

In front of this screen I show a component that fills to the screen with a black color alpha of 0.7.

```
<s:Group id="screen" width="100%" height="100%">
    // components...
</s:Group>

<s:Group id="alpha" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill><s:SolidColor alpha=".7"/></s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    // components...
</s:Group>
```

What I want is to display a component that is behind (in "screen" group) in front of "alpha" screen.

As it is in different group I cant use `depth`

BUT, I CAN'T remove that component from "screen" and add it in "alpha" via `addElement()`

Comment: Are you wanting to do it purely through XML? (Assuming that is XML, I've not used much myself)  In pure AS3 you could use `swapChildren(child1, child2)` or `setChildIndex(objectParent, desiredDepth)` but I'm unfamiliar with the format you have posted.

Comment: @sirn That is MXML; which an XML language for Flex applications.  Using the swapChildren or setChildIndex is the correct approach; but you'll need to move the rect out of the alpha group to do what you want; because int he current structure; Rect is a child of alpha. You'll never be able to to put some child of one component behind another while the rest of the children in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the "alpha" group inside of "screen" group and then set depth="1" to components that you want above the "alpha" group.

```
<s:Group id="screen" width="100%" height="100%">
    // components
    <s:Group id="alpha" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:fill><s:SolidColor alpha="0.7"/></s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
```